# Handle multiple domains without restarting HTTP server

Tags: apache, nginx, dns

Let's assume I have multiple domains pointing to one server.
I know that I can have multiple virtual hosts in Apache for example, but every time  I want to add a new website I have to change the configuration and restart the server.

I am looking for hosting multiple domain names without having to create a config file each time.
Why ? because after creating a config file, I have then to restart the HTTP server which means that each domain I add will block all the other domains for a period of time.

Basically I want a config or program that points dynamically each domain to a sub-folder of my main source code without having to create a config file or restarting the HTTP server.

Please let me know if this is doable with the current HTTP servers or if not point me to some resources that will help me do this programatically.

Comment: If you have high-availability demands, you might need a separate load balancer and a cluster of webservers. Especially if you can't stand such a short time of service interruptions.

Comment: @OlafKock, thank you for your answer can you point me to some resources that use this kind of architecture ?

Answer (score 0):

With most standard web servers you simply cannot do this without a restart or at least reload of the service (so it picks up the new configs).

Of course you could build your own solution, based on your requirements.

Comment: Any links to how I may do this programatically ?

Comment: Nope, and that would not be near to simple to accomplish :) There is a reason the current solutions are not built this way. Also how would your solution know when to load a new config, what if that config is wrong at the time you save the file for  new domain, and this brings all of your vhosts down?? There are a lot of considerations and planning for errors that needs to be thought through..

Answer (score 0):

You can reload the server without restart it, a reload keep the active connections up, so you can load the changes in your configuration without restarting the server.

Command for nginx:  `nginx -s reload`

I suggest to use `nginx -t && nginx -s reload` in order to check the configuration before reloading

Command for Apache: `apachectl -k graceful`, `systemctl reload httpd.service`, `service apache2 reload`, `service httpd reload` (it depends on your environment)